# MySQL count unique over multiple tables

Tags: mysql, performance

I have two tables:

```
products            product_eans
+--+-----------+    +----------+-------------+
|id|name       |    |product_id|ean          |
+--+-----------+    +----------+-------------+
| 1|hello world|    |         1|4053804303361|
+--+-----------+    +----------+-------------+
| 2|hello mars |    |         1|4053804304788|
+--+-----------+    +----------+-------------+
                    |         2|4053804304825|
                    +----------+-------------+
```

I now want to count the (unique) products that has the string *4788* in their name or in one of their EANs. The result in the example would be 1 (one product has an EAN that contains the search string *4788*)

I have managed this with

```
SELECT
        COUNT(DISTINCT products.id) AS count
    FROM
        products
    WHERE
        products.name LIKE "%4788%" OR 
        (SELECT
            GROUP_CONCAT(ean)
        FROM
            product_eans
        WHERE
            product_id = product.id) LIKE "%4788%"`
```

but it’s incredible **slow** with thousands of rows in both tables.

What is the most efficient way for a query like this?

Comment: Guess what will happen if there is an `ean` of `14778` or `47781`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After being inspired by Used_By_Already, I came across a simple idea:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT products.id) AS count
FROM
    products
WHERE
    products.name LIKE "%4788%" OR
    products.id in (SELECT product_id FROM product_eans WHERE ean "%4788%")
```

It's super fast now. So thanks to Used_By_Already.

Answer (score 1):

Using "double-ended wildcards" is never going to be fast because you won't get use of indexing so the tables will be scanned. An inner join is probably the most efficient

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.products_id)
FROM product_eans e
inner join products p on e.products_id = p.id
WHERE e.ean LIKE '%4788%'
OR p.name LIKE '%4788%'
```

but one other possibility is to avoid the OR in tha wheer clause by using a union query like this:

```
  SELECT
        COUNT(*)
  FROM (
        SELECT
              product_id
        FROM product_eans
        WHERE ean LIKE '%4788%'
        UNION
        SELECT
              id
        FROM products
        WHERE name LIKE '%4788%'
  ) d
```